# How to get view to which jobs are tied in jenkins

Tags: java, api, jenkins

I'm able to get the list of jobs that are present using URL - jenkinsurl/.../api/xml.
I also want to know to which view that job is attached.
Is there any API that jenkins provides to get the view name.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found when searching for the same.

**Not likely, as there is no view name for a job.  It’s an N:M relationship between jobs and views: a view can have any number of jobs, and a job can have any number of views.  I suspect that jobs don’t “know” what view they’re in.**

I hope this could help you proceed further